# DateTime showing different date when converted to date

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I am currrently working with Java JODATIME DateTime. I have a dateTime as 2015-09-08T11:00:00.000Z , When I convert to date using toDate().

I am getting the date object as Tue Sep 08 06:00:00 CDT 2015.

```
DateTime dateTime =  2015-09-08T11:00:00.000Z; // Not a string I am getting this date from another API.
Date date = dateTime.toDate(); //Tue Sep 08 06:00:00 CDT 2015.
```

May I know what is the thing happening here?

Comment: Looks like the issue of timezone!

Comment: There's no issue actually. CDT is `-0500`, and your DateTIme is in `0000` timezones. So there's a difference of `5 hours`.

Answer (score 1):

A `Date` object simply holds the number of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970 UTC. It does not contain presentation logic, so your comment that it equates to 6am CDT shows that something (your IDE, or some date formatter) has applied a timezone in order to render the date to a human readable form. The code is actually working correctly.

Comment: `Date.toString()` always uses the system local time zone. A `Date` object doesn't contain any formatting *state*, but the class contains a bare minimum of presentation *logic* in `toString`. (I've fixed the epoch year, btw - I assume that was just a typo.)

Comment: You're quite right - it was a typo. And yes the toString has bare formatting, but the essence is that the `Date` object contains a UTC time, ready to be formatted into any timezone the user requires.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are calling the `toString` method on the java.util.Date object. That class’ implementation of `toString` has the confusing feature of silently applying your JVM’s current default time zone to the date-time value as it generates a String representation.

The java.util.Date object itself has no time zone, and is always in UTC.

This is one of many reasonable avoid these old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. Use [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), now built into Java 8 and later. For older versions of Java, use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Also this topic has been addressed many many times before on StackOverflow. Please search before posting.

A quick bit of example code in java.time. An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Your input string happens to be in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format which java.time uses by default when parsing/generating strings. So you can parse directly without bothering to specify a parsing pattern.

```
String input = "2015-09-08T11:00:00.000Z";
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input );
```

Adjust that `Instant` into a specific time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

Search StackOverflow.com for many more examples of java.time.

---

Actually there is a time zone buried in the source code of java.util.Date but is ignored for practical purposes.